# Why are my params missing the outer `service` object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I get these params when I post this form:

```
Processing by ServicesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LrWV0NDir", 
  "bike_part_id"=>["9", "10"], "description" => "fix me",
  "bike_id"=>"8"}
```

How should I craft the form to have the **service** object on top?

E.g:

```
  service: {
    bike_id: 1,
    bike_part_ids:  [1,2]
  }
```

My `service_parms` will not allow this as **service** is missing:

```
 def service_params
   params.require(:service).permit(:description, :log, :due_date, 
   :bike_id, :user_id, :completed, bike_part_id: [])
 end
```

**The form**

```
.form-horizontal
  = form_for [@bike, @service] do |f|
    - @part = @bike_part


    - if @part.present?
      h2 = "Ny service for #{@part.kind}"
      br
      br
      .well
        - if @part.service_due?
          h4 På tide med ny service
          p
            = "Denne delen bør ha service hver #{@part.service_interval} km"
            br
            = "Siste service på #{@part.kind} ble gjort da sykkelen hadde gått"
            em = " #{@part.service_done_at_bike_distance} km"
        /= collection_select(:service, :bike_part_id, @bike.bike_parts.all,
          :id, :kind, prompt: true, selected: @part.id )


    .form-group
      = f.label :description
      = f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control', rows: 6,
        placeholder: "- What does the customer want us to help with? \n" \
        "- Have we agreed upon a price? \n" \
        "- Anything we should check up and call the customer about?"

    - unless @service.new_record?
      .form-group
        = f.label :log
        = f.text_area :log, class: 'form-control', rows: 6,
          placeholder: "Describe what's done.."

    .form-group
      = f.label :due_date
      br
      = f.datetime_select :due_date, start_year: Time.now.year,
        end_year: Time.now.year+1, order: [:day, :month, :year]

    - unless @service.new_record?
      .form-group
        .checkbox
          label
            = check_box_tag 'service[completed]', true, @service.completed
            | Ferdig



    .form-group
        = f.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary', value: 'Save'
        = link_to 'tilbake', :back, class: 'btn'
```

**routes**

```
 bike_services GET    /bikes/:bike_id/services(.:format)      services#index
               POST   /bikes/:bike_id/services(.:format)      services#create
```

**The HTML generated from the rails view**

```
<form action="/bikes/8/services" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="qNNd/A8lpCP1p4c7Bp5K1YZB/n+SfHztcOadQuFE/vfYwTCUx4TwESdSGWINK3Jiq1O6BmtLrWV0NDir+4a7cg==">
              <table>
                <tbody><tr>
                  <th>
                    Del
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Service intervall
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Antall km til neste service
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    cassette
                  </td>
                  <td align="right">
                    3000.0
                  </td>
                  <td align="right">
                    In 3
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="bike_part_id[]" id="bike_part_id_" value="9">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    chain
                  </td>
                  <td align="right">
                    3000.0
                  </td>
                  <td align="right">
                    In 3
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="bike_part_id[]" id="bike_part_id_" value="10">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    front break
                  </td>
                  <td align="right">
                    3000.0
                  </td>
                  <td align="right">
                    Overdue by -187,9
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="bike_part_id[]" id="bike_part_id_" value="11">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    front derailleur
                  </td>
                  <td align="right">
                    1000.0
                  </td>
                  <td align="right">
                    Overdue by -189,9
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="bike_part_id[]" id="bike_part_id_" value="12">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody></table>
              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="registrer en service"></form>
```

Comment: It looks weird because `description` key is missing too in the `params` hash

Comment: @Pavan, I've clarified the question. Please have an other look. :-)

Comment: My point is that the ***server log*** doesn't contain `description` key even though the ***form*** has it.

Comment: I removed it from the example to save space. Put it back now. I'm still wondering why the outer `service` object is missing. :)

Comment: Ok. Try inspecting the fields in your form. Does the name of fields has `service` appended to it. ex. `"service[description]"`?

Comment: Nope, it does not. I've added the HTML form to the original post too.

Comment: Where do these checkboxes come from? Not from the `form` code you posted

Comment: Why not use form helpers? They ensure correct input names

Comment: You have a form AND a HTML form:?  The `form` file generates the HTML for you. If you wrote that HTML, then you didn't follow the nesting convention of `name` attributes for a form and you didn't include the fields specified in the `form`.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn The second one is the generated html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the .form-group divs inside the form you created.  Slim goes by indents and you basically end your form on the same line you created it since the .form-group divs are at the same level the form_for is specified at.  Indent all your code inside the form_for one more time like:

```
.form-horizontal
  = form_for [@bike, @service] do |f|
    .form-group
      = f.label :description
      = f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control', rows: 6,
    .form-group
      = f.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary', value: 'Save'
```

**UPDATE**:  Looks like your question was edited and indents were added...I'll leave this here in case you actually pasted your slim code as it was in which case you need it shown as the edited post above or my answer.